# Get an Exception while Generating jasper Report

Tags: android

Exception net.sf.jasper-reports.engine.JR Run time Exception: 
Error creating SAX parser in Android Studio After Adding a xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar and jasperreports-5.6.0.jar File in lib Folder.How to Generate a Jasper Report from Real Time Data.

Comment: Could you post the full exception trace?

Comment: Exception net.sf.jasper-reports.engine.JR Run time Exception: Error  creating SAX parse
It is Possible to generate a JASPER File From Android

Comment: I have used jasper report in Android before, you just need to know that jasper consumes lots of RAM in Android. BTW have you designed your jrxml file, and is it ready to use?

Comment: i am Import a jrxml File from Web app i need to Reuse it now Please help can you Please share your Code its very helpful for me

Comment: That's great, then you have a designed jrxml file, that maps your data classes attribute on your report. are you going to generate pdf or excel ?

Comment: generating a pdf File    Is it Working for me or Not                                                   AssetManager assetManager = getContext().getAssets();
                    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("DCR_monthly.jasper");
                    Log.e("Input Stream ", inputStream + "");
                    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStream);
                    print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, map, connect);

Comment: What I had done was using "XML" for passing data to jrxml, I can provide you my pieces of code in about an hour, I think it helps. However I still believe that generating report on server side would be more efficient.

Comment: Thanks For Support  i am waiting i am using .jasper file instead

Comment: Sorry I'm late bro, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the following class, just take care of package name

```
package com.sunflower.visitor.report;


import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JRDataSource;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JRException;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JRExporterParameter;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JasperExportManager;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JasperFillManager;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JasperPrint;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.JasperReport;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.data.JsonDataSource;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.export.JRPdfExporterParameter;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.type.RunDirectionEnum;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.util.JRLoader;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.util.JRXmlUtils;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.registry.ApiRegistry;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.repo.FileResourceLoader;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.repo.RepositoryManager;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.repo.SubreportUtil;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.sql.IConnection;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.sql.factory.ISqlFactory;
import org.oss.pdfreporter.uses.org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class PdfReporter {
    private final String mPdfOutputFolder;
    private final String mPdfOutputName;
    private final String mJrxmlFilePath;
    private Map<JRExporterParameter, Object> mExportParameters = new HashMap();
    private Map<String, Object> mFillParameters = new HashMap();
    private String mSubreportName;
    private String mSubreportLocation;
    private boolean mXmlReport;
    private boolean mSqlReport;
    private boolean mJsonReport;
    private String mXmlDataFile;
    private String mXmlXPath;
    private String mSqlPath;
    private String mSqlUsername;
    private String mSqlPassword;
    private String mJsonDataFile;
    private String mJsonExpression;

    public PdfReporter(String jrxmlFilePath, String outputFolder, String outputPdfName) {
        this.mPdfOutputFolder = outputFolder;
        this.mPdfOutputName = outputPdfName;
        this.mJrxmlFilePath = jrxmlFilePath;
    }

    public void setExportParameters(Map<JRExporterParameter, Object> exporterParameters) {
        this.mExportParameters.putAll(exporterParameters);
    }

    public void setFillParameters(Map<String, Object> fillParameters) {
        this.mFillParameters.putAll(fillParameters);
    }

    public static RepositoryManager getRepositoryManager() {
        return RepositoryManager.getInstance();
    }

    private String exportWithoutDataSource() throws Exception {
        return this.exportFromXml((String)null, (String)null);
    }

    public PdfReporter setXmlSource(String xmlDataFile, String xmlXpath) {
        if(!this.mSqlReport && !this.mJsonReport) {
            this.mXmlReport = true;
            this.mXmlDataFile = xmlDataFile;
            this.mXmlXPath = xmlXpath;
            return this;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can\'t change report type, data source already set");
        }
    }

    public PdfReporter setSqlSource(String databasePath, String username, String password) {
        if(!this.mXmlReport && !this.mJsonReport) {
            this.mSqlReport = true;
            this.mSqlPath = databasePath;
            this.mSqlUsername = username;
            this.mSqlPassword = password;
            return this;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can\'t change report type, data source already set");
        }
    }

    public PdfReporter setJsonSource() {
        return this.setJsonSource((String)null, (String)null);
    }

    public PdfReporter setJsonSource(String jsonDataFile) {
        return this.setJsonSource(jsonDataFile, (String)null);
    }

    public PdfReporter setJsonSource(String jsonDataFile, String selectExpression) {
        if(!this.mXmlReport && !this.mSqlReport) {
            this.mJsonReport = true;
            this.mJsonDataFile = jsonDataFile;
            this.mJsonExpression = selectExpression;
            return this;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Can\'t change report type, data source already set");
        }
    }

    public String exportPdf() throws Exception {
        return this.mXmlReport?this.exportFromXml(this.mXmlDataFile, this.mXmlXPath):(this.mSqlReport?this.exportSqlReport(this.mSqlPath, this.mSqlUsername, this.mSqlPassword):(this.mJsonReport?this.exportJsonReport():this.exportWithoutDataSource()));
    }

    private String exportFromXml(String xmlDataFile, String xmlXpath) throws Exception {
        ApiRegistry.initSession();

        String var5;
        try {
            JasperDesign design = this.loadReport(this.mJrxmlFilePath);
            design.setColumnDirection(RunDirectionEnum.RTL);

            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
            var5 = this.exportReport(report, xmlDataFile, xmlXpath);
        } finally {
            ApiRegistry.dispose();
        }

        return var5;
    }

    private String exportSqlReport(String databasePath, String username, String password) throws Exception {
        ApiRegistry.initSession();
        IConnection sqlDataSource = null;

        String var10;
        try {
            JasperDesign design = this.loadReport(this.mJrxmlFilePath);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
            ISqlFactory sqlFactory = ApiRegistry.getSqlFactory();
            sqlDataSource = sqlFactory.newConnection(databasePath, username, password);
            this.processSubreport();
            JasperPrint printReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, this.mFillParameters, sqlDataSource);
            String pathToPdfFile = this.mPdfOutputFolder + "/" + this.mPdfOutputName + ".pdf";
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printReport, pathToPdfFile, this.mExportParameters);
            var10 = pathToPdfFile;
        } finally {
            this.close(sqlDataSource);
            ApiRegistry.dispose();
        }

        return var10;
    }

    private String exportReport(JasperReport compiledReport, String xmlDataFile, String xmlXpath) throws Exception {
        ApiRegistry.initSession();
        Object dataSource = null;
        InputStream isXmlData = null;

        String var8;
        try {
            if(xmlDataFile == null) {
                dataSource = new JREmptyDataSource();
            } else {
                isXmlData = FileResourceLoader.getInputStream(xmlDataFile);
                JRXmlDataSource printReport = new JRXmlDataSource(isXmlData, xmlXpath);
                printReport.setDatePattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
                dataSource = printReport;
            }

            this.processSubreport();
            JasperPrint printReport1 = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport, this.mFillParameters, (JRDataSource)dataSource);
            String pathToPdfFile = this.mPdfOutputFolder + "/" + printReport1.getName() + ".pdf";
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printReport1, pathToPdfFile, this.mExportParameters);
            var8 = pathToPdfFile;
        } finally {
            this.close(isXmlData);
            ApiRegistry.dispose();
        }

        return var8;
    }

    private String exportJsonReport() throws Exception {
        ApiRegistry.initSession();
        JsonDataSource jsonDataSource = null;

        String var6;
        try {
            JasperDesign design = this.loadReport(this.mJrxmlFilePath);
            JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(design);
            JasperPrint printReport = null;
            this.processSubreport();
            if(this.mJsonDataFile == null) {
                printReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, this.mFillParameters);
            } else {
                InputStream pathToPdfFile = FileResourceLoader.getInputStream(this.mJsonDataFile);
                jsonDataSource = new JsonDataSource(pathToPdfFile, this.mJsonExpression);
                printReport = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, this.mFillParameters, jsonDataSource);
            }

            String pathToPdfFile1 = this.mPdfOutputFolder + "/" + printReport.getName() + ".pdf";
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(printReport, pathToPdfFile1, this.mExportParameters);
            var6 = pathToPdfFile1;
        } finally {
            this.close(jsonDataSource);
            ApiRegistry.dispose();
        }

        return var6;
    }

    public PdfReporter addSubreport(String subreportName, String location) throws JRException {
        this.mSubreportName = subreportName;
        this.mSubreportLocation = location;
        return this;
    }

    private void processSubreport() throws JRException {
        if(this.mSubreportLocation != null && this.mSubreportName != null) {
            JasperReport subreport = SubreportUtil.loadSubreport(this.mSubreportLocation);
            this.mFillParameters.put(this.mSubreportName, subreport);
        }

    }

    public PdfReporter addEncryption(boolean is128bitKey, String userPassword, String ownerPassword, int permissions) {
        this.mExportParameters.put(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_ENCRYPTED, Boolean.TRUE);
        this.mExportParameters.put(JRPdfExporterParameter.IS_128_BIT_KEY, is128bitKey?Boolean.TRUE:Boolean.FALSE);
        this.mExportParameters.put(JRPdfExporterParameter.USER_PASSWORD, userPassword);
        this.mExportParameters.put(JRPdfExporterParameter.OWNER_PASSWORD, ownerPassword);
        this.mExportParameters.put(JRPdfExporterParameter.PERMISSIONS, Integer.valueOf(permissions));
        return this;
    }

    public PdfReporter addJSONParams(String datePattern, String numberPattern, Locale jsonLocale, Locale country) {
        this.mFillParameters.put("net.sf.jasperreports.json.date.pattern", datePattern);
        this.mFillParameters.put("net.sf.jasperreports.json.number.pattern", numberPattern);
        this.mFillParameters.put("JSON_LOCALE", jsonLocale);
        this.mFillParameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE", country);
        return this;
    }

    public PdfReporter addXMLParams(String datePattern, String numberPattern, Locale xmlLocale, Locale country) {
        this.mFillParameters.put("XML_DATE_PATTERN", datePattern);
        this.mFillParameters.put("XML_NUMBER_PATTERN", numberPattern);
        this.mFillParameters.put("XML_LOCALE", xmlLocale);
        this.mFillParameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE", country);
        return this;
    }

    public PdfReporter addSubReportXMLDocument(String xmlDataFile) throws JRException {
        Document document = JRXmlUtils.parse(JRLoader.getLocationInputStream(xmlDataFile));
        this.mFillParameters.put("XML_DATA_DOCUMENT", document);
        return this;
    }

    public PdfReporter newResourceBundle(String classPath, Locale locale) {
        this.mFillParameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE", locale);
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(classPath, locale);
        this.mFillParameters.put("REPORT_RESOURCE_BUNDLE", resourceBundle);
        return this;
    }

    public PdfReporter addFillParameter(String key, Object value) {
        this.mFillParameters.put(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    private JasperDesign loadReport(String reportFileName) throws Exception {
        InputStream isReport = null;

        JasperDesign var3;
        try {
            isReport = FileResourceLoader.getInputStream(reportFileName);
            var3 = JRXmlLoader.load(isReport);
        } finally {
            this.close(isReport);
        }

        return var3;
    }

    private void close(Closeable stream) throws Exception {
        if(stream != null) {
            stream.close();
        }

    }
}
```

And look at the following code, FactureHeader and Article are myown data classes, you need to replace it with our data class(es) :

```
public String exportFactures(Activity activity, FactureHeader factureHeader, List<Article> factureArticles) throws Exception {
        PdfReporter exporter = getExporter("FactureReport.jrxml", "crosstabs", "extra-fonts");
        Map<JRExporterParameter, Object> map = new HashMap<JRExporterParameter, Object>();
        map.put(JRExporterParameter.CHARACTER_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        exporter.setExportParameters(map);
        exporter.addXMLParams("YYYY/MM/dd", "#,##0", new Locale("ar", "EG"), new Locale("ar", "EG"));

        return exporter.setXmlSource(XmlStorage.saveXmlFacturePdfReportArticle(activity, factureHeader, factureArticles), "/facture/article").exportPdf();
    }


private PdfReporter getExporter(String jrxmlPath, String reportFolder, String extraFolder) {
        //path to root folder with all reports
        final String rootFolder = getRootFolder();
        final String resourceFolder = getResourcesFolder();

        RepositoryManager repo = PdfReporter.getRepositoryManager();
        repo.reset();
        repo.setDefaultResourceFolder(resourceFolder);
        repo.setDefaulReportFolder(rootFolder + RepositoryManager.PATH_DELIMITER + "jrxml" + RepositoryManager.PATH_DELIMITER + reportFolder);
```

And there is the XMLStorage class to generate the xml file which hands the data to jrxml file, pay attention that you have to configure the method as your data:

```
package com.sunflower.visitor.data.xml;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.Xml;
import com.sunflower.visitor.data.tempholder.FactureDataHolder;
import com.sunflower.visitor.dto.Article;
import com.sunflower.visitor.dto.FactureArticle;
import com.sunflower.visitor.dto.FactureHeader;
import com.sunflower.visitor.util.FileUtil;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Joe on 13/02/2016.
 */
public class XmlStorage {
    public static String saveXmlFacturePdfReportArticle(Activity activity, FactureHeader factureHeader, List<Article> factureArticles){

        final String xmlFile = activity.getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/reports/resources" + "/facture.xml";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fileos = new FileOutputStream (new File(xmlFile));
            XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = Xml.newSerializer();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            xmlSerializer.setOutput(writer);
            xmlSerializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
            xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "facture");

            for(int i=0; i<factureArticles.size(); i++) {

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "article");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "date");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureHeader.getFactureDate());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "date");
                Log.d("article", "factureHeader.getFactureDate() : " + factureHeader.getFactureDate());

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "facture_number");
                xmlSerializer.text("\u202E" + factureHeader.getFactureNumber());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "facture_number");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "customer");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureHeader.getCustomerName());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "customer");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "comment");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureHeader.getComment());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "comment");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "row");
                xmlSerializer.text("" + (i + 1));
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "row");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "article_name");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getArticleName());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "article_name");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "orders");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getOrders() + "");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "orders");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "unit");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getUnitName());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "unit");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "unit_number");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getUnitNumberInDouble() + "");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "unit_number");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "fee");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getSelectedPrice() + "");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "fee");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "sum_fee");
                xmlSerializer.text("" + (factureArticles.get(i).getOrders() * factureArticles.get(i).getUnitNumberInDouble() * factureArticles.get(i).getSelectedPrice()));
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "sum_fee");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "row_off");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getOffPercent());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "row_off");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "levy");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getConfigurableLevy());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "levy");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "jogs");
                xmlSerializer.text(factureArticles.get(i).getConfigurableJogs());
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "jogs");

                xmlSerializer.startTag(null, "factureprice");
                xmlSerializer.text(FactureDataHolder.getFacturePrice() + "");
                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "factureprice");

                xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "article");
            }
            xmlSerializer.endTag(null, "facture");
            xmlSerializer.endDocument();

            xmlSerializer.flush();
            String dataWrite = writer.toString();
            fileos.write(dataWrite.getBytes());
            fileos.close();

            return xmlFile;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

        if (null != extraFolder) {
            repo.addExtraReportFolder(resourceFolder + RepositoryManager.PATH_DELIMITER + extraFolder);
        }
        repo.addExtraReportFolder(resourceFolder);

        PdfReporter reporter = new PdfReporter(jrxmlPath, getOuputPdfFolder(), getFilenameFromJrxml(jrxmlPath));

        return  reporter;
    }
```

And make sure you have added jasper jar files correctly to the project. Please let me know what happens, it's been a long time since the last time I used Jasper in Android and maybe there are somethings I am missing.

Comment: I had used jasperreports-5.1.0

Comment: Thanks can you share your Skype id pls